# Differentiability at a point of nondifferentiability?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I have this piecewise function $f(x,y)=-xy/(x^2+y^2)$ and at (0,0) $f(x,y) = 0$ .Clearly this function is not continuous nor differentiable at $(0,0)$(since the limit doesn't exist **the two path test proves this**). However, when I am asked to take the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ (WRT), it wants me to evaluate it at $(0,0)$. However, this partial derivative is undefined at $0,0)$. The correct method asks me to use the limit definition of a partial derivative to evaluate it. Why are we able to use the limit definition of the partial derivative to evaluate the partial derivative if the partial derivative of $f$ WRT x at $(0,0)$ gives us division by $0$?
Does this is mean that if your function is not continuous at a point, the function's derivative still can be evaluated at that point? Also, how would this look visually? Thanks!

Comment: Unless you tell us what $f(0,0)$ **is**, then $f$ is **undefined** at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Sorry about that. Its a piecewise function where it is defined everywhere except (0,0). At (0,0) f(x,y)=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula
$$
f'_x=\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{-xy}{x^2+y^2} \right)
= \frac{x^2 y - y^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
$$
is only valid for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, since it doesn't take the value $f(0,0)=0$ into account at all.

So the fact that this formula gives an undefined value when try to you plug in $(x,y)=(0,0)$ has nothing to do with the separate fact that $f'_x(0,0)$ does exist and equals zero (since $f(x,0)$ is a constant function – it's zero for all $x$, including $x=0$).

Comment: Thank you. This clarifies a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{a\to 0} \frac a a $ exist and equals $1$. You cannot put $a=0$ and say that the limit is undefined claiming  that it involves division by $0$. When you take limit as $ a\to 0$ you are supposed to consider values of $a$ close to $0$ but not $0$ itself. Since $\frac a a=1$ for $a \neq 0$ the limit is $1$.

I hope this clears your confusion.

Comment: But then how does this pertain to the derivative? Here the function is not approaching the same point so what about the slope. It just doesn't make sense in terms of slope.

Comment: @Vostro2011 The function is $0$ whenever $y=0$ . So the slope is $0$ and the partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ at the origin is $0$.